# WEC : How to uniquely identify logs in `Forwarded Events` channel

Tags: windows, event-log

Looking for more information or at least suggestions on alternatives to EventRecordID as an index when using the Windows Event Collector.
When working with an individual server and individual Eventlog, the EventRecordID element can be used as an index to keep your place when crawling through events in order.
However, when using the Windows Event Collector, the events retain their original EventRecordID in the ForwardedEvents log.  That makes it difficult at best to keep track of where you were when crawling through events with a script/program.
The date/timestamp doesn't help either, as events can come in from other systems after you have moved past a given date/time.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a way to track, bookmark, or index events in ForwardedEvents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BookmarkID

[See how to get it with the Microsoft example in C++ here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/bookmarking-events)

or like I did with C#

```
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("ForwardedEvents", PathType.LogName);
EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);
EventRecord myevent = logReader.ReadEvent();
string bookmark = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValue(myevent.Bookmark, "BookmarkText").ToString();
```

[ReflectionHelper is not from me. Source here](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/12/c-how-to-set-or-get-value-of-a-private-or-internal-property-through-the-reflection/)